# Stalingrad Pocket 2nd ed Air Power Barrage Shift

Tags: stalingrad-pocket-ii

According to rule 1.10g Divisional Integrity Artillery Bonus: "Artillery which does not have a friendly unit adjacent to the intended target ... will receive a (leftward) shift on the Barrage Table..."

Does this shift apply to air units attacking without a spotter? Does it apply if air units are barraging with artillery units without a spotter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

Yes.

The modifier is listed on the barrage table and applies to barrage combat regardless of source. It does not draw distinction between air or artillery.